# Facebook login under iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

So there is a lot of information on the web, but much of it seems to be deprecated.

Inside of my app I am attempting to let a user login using the `FacebookSDK`.

I would like to open a `FBSession`, present the user with a facebook login screen, and then get their login Token.

I have an App Id and a App Secret, and inside of the project info I populated the FacebookAppID(the info.plist).

I am not sure what to do the secret ID. I see old references to:

```
session = [FBSession sessionForApplication:@"=asdfasdfasdf" secret:@"asdfasdfasdf" delegate:self];
```

But this appears to be deprecated. The simple version of my method is like so:

```
    -(IBAction)fbLogin:(id)sender
    {
        NSString *fbAccessToken;
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        //If the user has a facebook session already open
        if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
        {
            fbAccessToken = [appDelegate.session accessTokenData].accessToken;
            #ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog(@"%@\nFacebook Token = %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), fbAccessToken);
            #endif
        }
        else // there is no facebook session
        {
            appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
            [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState status,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                [self fbLogin:self];

            }];
         }
     }
```

I am new to Objective-C and Xcode. So I imagine there is more than one or two things I am doing incorrectly.

This guy seems to have some solid info in it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0

But I really have not been able to find out much about how I need to use my 'App Secret' from my facebook developers page.

Thanks

Comment: if u added the app id in .plist it will be enough one don't need of app secret , will u need the Facebook login code

Comment: The app secret should be secret. If you put it in your app that your users downloads it is not secret anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you don't need to use the app secret in your app. I've followed the same link that you have added in your question but since I prefer to have my own login UI, I followed [this particular section from the tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#api-overview). With the app id added to my app `plist` file, this is how I get a user logged into Facebook from my app:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {


                                      // Retrieve the app delegate
                                      AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                                      // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
                                      [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];

                                      if(!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen) {

                                          // Do something else
                                      }
                                  }];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: now in Facebook ver 2.o deprecated the [@"basic_info"] and replace the public_profile

Comment: Thanks. I assume you are including the if(!error ...){do work} for example sake. Or would there be any reason to just handle that case in here and not in the sessionStateChanged method(not that this is a huge deal either way)?

Comment: Not really, while the sessionStateChanged: method is meant to handle state changes in the app, I prefer to have control over the flow from the controller I login with. Hence the condition to make sure everything's alright to proceed :)